# iPhone Configuration Utility - Add webclip for webapp

Tags: iphone, web-applications, safari, app-config, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm using Apple iPhone Configuration Utility to configure in-company mobile phones. I'd like to add to home screen an icon for a in-house web application we have developed. Using the Web Clip section, it's easy to add the webclip to home screen, however, we have two issues:

- The webclip doesn't show up the png icon defined for the page (in meta tags).
- The page loads up in Safari but is not "stand-alone" (fullscreen) (same thing, this property is defined in meta tags).

Note these issues are not encountered when adding the webclip to the home screen directly from Safari Mobile on the device.

Best

Comment: I'd argue that this belongs on Super User, because it's more of a software issue than programming one.

Comment: @BradLarson: I disagree. This is part of app distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the iPhone Configuration Utility. There, in the section for web clip you can set full screen and and the icon. As far as I remember, you need to have those things set there and in the meta tags.

We use this feature quiet a lot and it works very well.

Comment: I can confirm that there are, indeed, checkboxes and settings for app icon and "full-screen mode". It's too bad that your WebClip won't automatically use your site's defined icon, but it does work.